# Colon in prerequisite, how to understand?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Below is a snippet from [Caffe](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe)'s [Makefile](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/Makefile#L604).

```
TEST_BIN_DIR = build/test
$(TEST_CXX_BINS): $(TEST_BIN_DIR)/%.testbin: $(TEST_CXX_BUILD_DIR)/%.o $(GTEST_OBJ) | $(DYNAMIC_NAME) $(TEST_BIN_DIR)
    @ echo LD $<
    $(Q)$(CXX) $(TEST_MAIN_SRC) $< $(GTEST_OBJ) \
    -o $@ $(LINKFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -l$(LIBRARY_NAME) -Wl,-rpath,$(ORIGIN)/../lib
```

What's the meaning of **the colon (:)** in the `TEST_CXX_BINS`'s prerequisite? Is it defining another rule in the prerequisite?

It's not the standard implicit rule or pattern rule. I've searched the web and GNU Make manual, find nothing for reference.

Comment: Nice question. Could that be a bug in the makefile ? Does it work? Indeed, in the manual, I see [semicolon syntax](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Rule-Syntax) or order-only-prerequisites, but not what you describe.

Comment: The Makefile works without any problem. @kebs

Comment: Aha, just see the description in the manual, see [Static Pattern Rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Usage). I had been missed this part. Haven't used this kind of rules before.

Comment: Yep, missed that too. I suggest you add that as answer, so it can be useful for future readers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a static pattern rule. The first part (left to first colon) is a list of targets. The second part defines a pattern to match against each target. The `%` stem that matches can then be used (or not) in the third part (right to the second colon) that lists the prerequisites. In your example `TEST_CXX_BINS` is supposed to be a list of targets. If one of these targets is, let's say, `$(TEST_BIN_DIR)/foo.testbin` (`build/test/foo.testbin`), then the following rule will be used for it:

```
$(TEST_BIN_DIR)/foo.testbin: $(TEST_CXX_BUILD_DIR)/foo.o $(GTEST_OBJ) | $(DYNAMIC_NAME) $(TEST_BIN_DIR)
    @ echo LD $<
    $(Q)$(CXX) $(TEST_MAIN_SRC) $< $(GTEST_OBJ) \
    -o $@ $(LINKFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -l$(LIBRARY_NAME) -Wl,-rpath,$(ORIGIN)/../lib
```

Note that the pre-requisites after the `|` are ordered pre-requisites: they must exist and are created if they don't, but if they do, make will not check whether they are more recent or not than the target.

Note also that the stem that matched can also be referred to in the recipe, thanks to the `$*` automatic variable.